# Deduping to newest items in a time bucket for time series

Tags: kql

Some data gets logged every 10 hours for machines with an ID.

I want to do a timeplot with one point for every 24 hours.

How do I get the newest datapoint by ID for these 24 hour buckets?

Comment: Wha's the point of using 24h window for data refresh rate of 10h? Why not just plot it As Is?

Comment: Because I want to do plot of the count of the items. And I don't know exactly when the 10h logging times fall, how long they last, and how precise the timing of this logging is. Hence I just want the newest chunk of logs for the 24h window. Or really any other kind of consistent deduping.

Comment: Please share a data sample (datatable / csv) that reflects your scenario.